# How redirect a button in reactnative

Tags: react-native

Hello i try to learn react-native and i try to do a button  who redirect at "settings":

```react
import Home from './components/Home'
import Settings from './components/Settings'

import * as React from 'react';

import { Text,Button,Navigation, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
      <Button

        title="Press me"
        color="#f194ff"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}
      />
      
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}
```

With tab navigator, component settings function but when i try with button "ReferenceError: navigation is not defined"

I know that's a simple question but i have already this error (i tried to do "onPress={() => component={Home}} but that doesn't function too

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did `import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';` but you didn't use it.
You probably should add:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

so that you can do:

```
 onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}
```

Comment: i already tried (i puted const navigation above app function) and it gives me Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component (i dont understand too)

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass `{ navigation }` as prop to `App`
Try this:

```
import Home from './components/Home'
import Settings from './components/Settings'

import * as React from 'react';

import { Text,Button,Navigation, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();



export default function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
      <Button

        title="Press me"
        color="#f194ff"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}
      />
      
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: that gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined" : s

Comment: https://medium.com/@ashleywnj/react-navigation-cannot-read-property-navigate-of-undefined-94ff5e9d3c2a

Comment: use the above link and try adding "export default withNavigation(Settings);" in Settings.js